# VHDL Synthesis Error

Tags: math, vhdl, fpga

I'm trying to write some simple math functions in VHDL but I keep getting the error

`found '0' definitions of operator "+", cannot determine exact overload matching definition for "+"` and I also get the same error about the division.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    signal delay_1           : integer range 0 to 127;
--  signal delay_2           : integer range 0 to 127;
--  signal delay_3           : integer range 0 to 127;
--  signal delay_4           : integer range 0 to 127;
    signal us_clock          : std_logic;
    signal ds_squareroot     : integer range 0 to 100;
    signal ds_squared        : integer range 0 to 5000;

 if(i_reset = '1') then
        delay_1        <= 0;
        delay_2        <= 0;
        delay_3        <= 0;
        delay_4        <= 0;
        ds_squared     <= 0;
        ds_squareroot  <= 0;
    elsif(rising_edge(i_clock)) then
        -- Delay 1 calculations
        ds_squared <= (i_distance*i_distance + (speaker_distance)*(speaker_distance));
        for n in 0 to 20 loop
            ds_squareroot <=  ((50 + ds_squared/ds_squareroot)/2);
        end loop;
        delay_1 <= (ds_squareroot - i_distance)/ speed_sound;
```

And here are the libraries that I'm calling.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;
```

Any advice as to why this is not compiling would be very helpful.

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109078/addition-in-vhdl-not-compiling, it has a similar error.

Comment: On a different note, you should not use `numeric_std` together with `std_logic_unsigned`, in fact, you shouldn't use `std_logic_unsigned` at all, since it's not actually a standard package.

Comment: This all has to do with which data types your signals have. Since you cut off the declarations, we can't really help you. Please make your code fragment VETSMOD. http://www.sigasi.com/content/vetsmod-get-better-feedback-your-vhdl-code-snippets

Comment: @youR.Fate.  I agree and disagree with you.  For math, I prefer the formalism of types unsigned and signed.  However, with the implicit definitions of ">", ">=", ..., I think it is wise to include an unsigned package to insure correct interpretation of A_slv8 > "100", particularly when A_slv8 is larger than 3 bits - particularly with newer engineers.  BTW, std_logic_unsigned works fine with numeric_std (in some ways, due to overloading, better than it does with std_logic_arith).  Numeric_std_unsigned will be better when synthesis tools support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that `i_distance` was a std_logic_vector and `speaker_distance` was an integer. Obviously this did not synthesize because of the difference in types here. I solved it with this simple expression

```
distance     <= conv_integer(i_distance);
```

This made both integers, which allowed the design to synthesize. Thanks for the help.